# Unmarshal complicated json data structure

Tags: go

I have a json file like this:

```
{
    "ABEV3":
        [
            {"Date":"2014-01-02","Open":17.3,"Close":17.39,"Low":17.18,"High":17.5,"Volume":8035400},
            {"Date":"2014-01-03","Open":17.41,"Close":16.9,"Low":16.9,"High":17.44,"Volume":24920500},
            {"Date":"2014-01-06","Open":16.95,"Close":16.8,"Low":16.55,"High":17.09,"Volume":9355100}
        ],
    "PETR4":
        [
            {"Date":"2014-01-02","Open":20.3,"Close":21.39,"Low":21.18,"High":21.5,"Volume":305464},
            {"Date":"2014-01-03","Open":20.41,"Close":21.9,"Low":21.9,"High":21.44,"Volume":10864},
            {"Date":"2014-01-06","Open":20.95,"Close":21.8,"Low":16.21,"High":21.09,"Volume":2016}
        ]
}
```

I am trying to use the code below to read this JSON but of course it does not work because I don't know how to make the string key (ABEV3, PETR4...) work together with the code below! I came up with `map[string]map[int]estrutura_da` but it does not work for some reason

```
    type estrutura_da struct {
        Date string
        Low float64
        High float64
        Open float64
        Close float64
        Volume int
    }       

    var da map[string]map[int]estrutura_da;
    
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(json_code),&da);
```

Do you have any suggestion how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `map[string]map[int]estrutura_da`, you should use `map[string][]estrutura_da`.

This because you have a JSON object (outer brackets) where each key is an array of objects. This corresponds to a Go map where each value is a slice of `estruntura_da`.